# C++/CLI SQL use ConnectionString with parameters as string

Tags: sql, command-line-interface, c++-cli

Trying to connect to SQL Server in VS2019 C++/CLI app.
This code works for me:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>

#using < System.dll>
#using < System.Data.dll>

using namespace std;
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Data;
using namespace System::Data::SqlClient;

bool ConnectToSQLServer(string server)
{
    SqlConnection cnn;
    cnn.ConnectionString = "Server=.\\SQLExpress;Integrated Security=SSPI;database=master";
    try
    {
        cnn.Open();
        cnn.Close();
        return true;
    }
    catch (SqlException ^ex)
    {
        return false;
    }

}

int main()
{
    if (ConnectToSQLServer(".\\SQLExpress"))
        printf("Connected!");
    else
        printf("Can not connect to SQL server!");

    return 0;
}
```

but when I change ConnectionString to this:

```
cnn.ConnectionString = "Server="+ server +";Integrated Security=SSPI;database=master";
```

I get compiler error:

> Error (active)    E1767   function
> "System::Data::SqlClient::SqlConnection::ConnectionString::set" cannot
> be called with the given argument list

The same error when I'm trying to use SqlConnectionStringBuilder:

```
SqlConnectionStringBuilder sqlBuilder;

sqlBuilder.DataSource = server;
```

So how to use string type parameters in ConnectionString?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CLR/CLI c++ you should not use `string` which is ambiguous. it may be `std::string` which is a different type from .NET's `string`. in particular it hard to tell when you use: `using namespace std;`.

What you should do is to use `String^` which is a reference to a .NET class.

so your code should be something like:

```
bool ConnectToSQLServer(String^ server)
{
    SqlConnection cnn;
    cnn.ConnectionString =  String::Format("Server={0};Integrated Security=SSPI;database=master", server);
    try
    {
        cnn.Open();
        cnn.Close();
        return true;
    }
    catch (SqlException ^ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And you can call it like this:

```
ConnectToSQLServer(gcnew String(".\\SQLExpress"));
```

Comment: Thanks! It's very simple to use